# taglib json create object from array

Tags: java, json, jsp, taglib

I am using json taglib in my jsp project. currently I am building my json object with this code:

```
<json:object prettyPrint="true">
    <json:array name="categories" var="cat" items="${categories}">
        <json:object>
            <json:property name="id" value="${cat.getId()}" />
            <json:array name="languages" var="lang" items="${cat.getCategorieslanguageses()}">
                <json:object>
                    <json:property name="${lang.getLanguages().getShortname()}" value="${lang.getValue()}" />
                </json:object>
            </json:array>
        </json:object>
    </json:array>
</json:object>
```

getCategorieslanguageses() returns an array of languages.
This code gives the following output:

```
{"categories": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "languages": [
      {"nl": "Vlees"},
      {"eng": "Meat"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "languages": [
      {"eng": "Fish"},
      {"nl": "Vis"}
    ]
  }
]}
```

So, this code works great, but the output I would prefer is:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "languages": [
                {
                    "nl": "Vis",
                    "eng": "Fish"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "languages": [
                {
                    "eng": "Meat",
                    "nl": "Vlees"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Could anyone help me to create this output with taglib json? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways of doing this.

1. Set `prettyPrint="true"` at every `json:object` or `json:array`.
2. By setting a page, request, session or application attribute `atg.taglib.json.prettyPrint` to either true or false.
3. By setting a context-parm in your web-app's web.xml file.

http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html

**EDIT**: At first i thought you were after formatting of the output.

```
"languages": [
      {"eng": "Fish"},
      {"nl": "Vis"}
    ]
```

The interpretation of this is, you have an array named `languages`, and in this array contains two objects, the first object has an attribute named `eng`, with value `Fish`. The second object has an attribute named `n1`, with value `Fish`.

```
"languages": [
                {
                    "eng": "Meat",
                    "nl": "Vlees"
                }
            ]
```

The interpretation of this is, you have an array named `languages`, and in this array contains just an object. The object has two attributes, one named `eng` with value `Meat`, the other named `n1` with value `Vlees`.

Just a curiosity, shouldn't

```
<json:property name="${lang.getLanguages().getShortname()}" value="${lang.getValue()}" />
```

be

```
<json:property name="${lang.getLanguages().getShortname()}" value="${lang.getLanguages().getValue()}" />
```

Comment: That is not what I wanted.

In the first result the languages are different objects with each one property. In the second result the languages is an array of properties.

I would like to create the second result.

Comment: Is it possible to create the second output with the taglib json and the code I provided?

Comment: No, lang contains the strings in the different languages and getlanguages() gets all the information about the language (name, shortname, ..)